# What is module.js 540 throw error?

Tags: node.js, npm

Just installing node/npm first time, Linux Fedora: I've followed all the instructions and tried every fix I can find on google.

```
Whenever I try to run npm install or npm test I get this: 
    module.js:540
    throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:22:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a [bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11134) and it has already been fixed in Node v5.4.1. Now it's working as usual.